# Instantiating modules with state

Tags: ocaml

In [Real World OCaml, Chapter 9 Functors](https://realworldocaml.org/v1/en/html/functors.html), it says

> Instantiating modules with state
>
> Modules can contain mutable states,
> and that means that you'll occasionally want to have multiple
> instantiations of a particular module, each with its own separate and
> independent mutable state. Functors let you automate the construction
> of such modules.

The book doesn't have much content on this sub topic. So I ask here.

Can anyone give me an example of *instantiating modules with state* to demonstrate

1. How to do that?
2. When to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. One example:

   `module Make (Arg : S) = struct
     (** ...Use Arg at will... *)
     let id = ref 0 
     let id () = incr id; !id
   end`

   Each instantiation result `Make(Arg)` will have it's own id generator.
2. If you don't feel you need it, just don't do it. In general having state makes reasoning about your code harder.